# reactjs - Infinity Render when refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

so I got an issue for my web. Let's say i have a code : (I copy this code from another question because it's similar to me)

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    //... simplified for purpose of this post
    handleChange(field, value, errors) {
        this.setState({field: {value:errors}});  //causes infinite loop when rendering 
    }

    generateProfileTabs () {
        return (
            <Bar
                onCounterChange={::this.handleChange} />
        );
    }
    render() {
         return (          
             <TabList>
                  {this.generateProfileTabs()}
             </TabList>
         );
    }
}    

class Bar extends React.Component {
    //... simplified for purpose of this post
    handleChange(field, value, errors) {
        //pass to parent via callback
        this.props.onCounterChange(field, value, errors);
    }
    render() {
        <FormControl type='text' value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    }
}
```

When I first load the web, This works like a charm. The child successfully pass the state to the parent with no infinite render or any errors. But, when I refresh the web, it will start render and render the parent (infinite loop). I need to close the browser and re-open it to make it works again, and it will do infinite render when I refresh the page.
Could you guys help me? Is there somethings wrong with my code? I know that something's wrong with my callback function, because when I remove the callback, I could refresh the page without seeing any infinite render. Thank you so much

Comment: Handlers usually takes event as first parameter

Comment: Thanks for the response!! Could you explain more? I'm new to react.

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
render() {
    <FormControl type='text' value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={()=>this.handleChange} />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!! Unfortunately, it's still not working. I think that the problem is in my parent code when I call ::this.handleChange , because I try to not call this callback on my child, and it's still did the infinite render "only when I refresh the page". Do you have other idea to solve this?

Comment: in your parent class Foo, you are calling <Bar> with the props onCounterChange, but in your Bar class you are reference it as this.props.handleChange. You either need to change the Foo reference to handleChange, or change the Bar reference to onCounterChange. And you might need to bind the on change functions.

Comment: Ah I miswrite over there, actually on my code I already change my Bar reference to onCounterChange, but still infinite render. Anyway, how to bind my on change functions? because onCounterChange is a props right? can I bind a props?

Comment: You can either bind the function in the constructor or you can do this: this.handleChange.bind(this). You are not binding the props, you are binding the function within the class that calls the props function.

Comment: Actually I already bind it with :: (:: is new syntax for .bind(this) ) but still when I refresh the page this binded handle change seems to be the reason for infinte loop

Comment: I think you want to bind the on change function in the Bar class. I'm not familiar with the new syntax of bind.